# pipenv ssh+git in non editable mode not working

Tags: python, git, ssh, version-control, pipenv

I'm trying to install a library with pipenv (2018.11.26) from git via ssh.

If I use git over https it works fine.

```
pipenv install git+https://<token>@<domain>/<organization>/<repository>#egg=<package>
```

But when I try ssh

```
pipenv install git+git@<domain>/<organization>/<repository>#egg=<package>
```

I get an error

```
"ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'git+git@<domain>/<organization>/<repository>#egg=<package>'\nHint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?\n"
Installation Failed
```

And with '==' it does not work either, I get a 'parse error'

The only way to make it work is in editable mode '-e'

```
pipenv install -e git+git@<domain>/<organization>/<repository>#egg=<package>
```

This saves the library in a src folder inside the virtual environment, whereas all other dependencies are in a Libs folder.

Do you guys know why and how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use full `ssh://` URL instead of `scp`-like URL:

```
pipenv install 'git+ssh://git@<domain>/<organization>/<repository>#egg=<package>'
```

See [the `pip` docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git) about supported URLs.